# How can I export Airbrake errors to Sentry?

Tags: sentry, airbrake

I want to start using Sentry instead of Airbrake
Is there a way to export the data I've collected on Airbrake to Sentry?

Comment: This may not be possible — does Airbrake have a bulk export mechanism?

Comment: Also, we'd be better able to help from support@getsentry.com (where we'd have more context on your account). :)